# Mark of the web links to other file types don't work

Tags: internet-explorer, hyperlink, local

If I have the mark of the web tag in my html I can't open pdf, xls, txt... no other file types will open than html. I need this tag as I need the html to work under ie.

Please suggest some workarounds for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good hack for this, the solution is just to get rid of the mark of the web comment and let the user to hit accept on the allow blocked content pop-up.